# Can AWS CodePipeline deploy with tags like the aws-cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I'm using AWS CodePipeline to deploy Cloudformation stacks. Previously I've used the aws-cli to create stacks with the `aws create-stack --tags` flag to propogate tags to the resources created. Is this possible with CodePipeline using the builtin CloudFormation provider? Here's an example of a deploy step I use:

```
    - Name: DeployToDev
      Actions:
        - Name: CreateChangeSetDev
          ActionTypeId:
            Category: Deploy
            Owner: AWS
            Version: 1
            Provider: CloudFormation
          Configuration:
            ChangeSetName: !Sub ${PipelineName}
            ActionMode: CHANGE_SET_REPLACE
            StackName: !Sub ${PipelineName}
            Capabilities: CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM
            TemplatePath: BuildOutput::outputtemplate.yaml
            TemplateConfiguration: !If [HasStackConfig,
                !Sub 'SourceOutput::${StackConfigDev}',
                 !Ref "AWS::NoValue"]
            RoleArn: !Sub arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/${CloudFormationDeploymentRole}
          InputArtifacts:
            - Name: BuildOutput
            - Name: SourceOutput
          RunOrder: 1
          RoleArn: !Sub arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/CICD-CF-Role-${AWS::Region}
        - Name: DeployChangeSetDev
          ActionTypeId:
            Category: Deploy
            Owner: AWS
            Version: 1
            Provider: CloudFormation
          Configuration:
            ChangeSetName: !Sub ${PipelineName}
            ActionMode: CHANGE_SET_EXECUTE
            StackName: !Sub ${PipelineName}
            RoleArn: !Sub arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/${CloudFormationDeploymentRole}
          InputArtifacts:
            - Name: BuildOutput
          RunOrder: 2
          RoleArn: !Sub arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/CICD-CF-Role-${AWS::Region}
```

Comment: I found this thread from 2017, and I'm starting to think this is not possible yet https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=253150&tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

> Under your Configuration add tags like this

```
StackTags:
    application-name: xxxx
    environment: xxxx
    owner: xxx
```

or try this if it doesn't work.

```
Tags:
    - application-name: xxxx
    - environment: xxxx
    - owner: xxx
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. But I can't get it to work. Both fails with `Value of property Configuration must be an object with String (or simple type) properties`.